# Python mysql cursor closes connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a python script that gets my mysql version, But I keep getting the same error "_mysql_exceptions.InterfaceError: (0, '')"

I went to the python2.7 console and tried the same,

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost",user="user", passwd="pass", db="example")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
>   self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>   raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   _mysql_exceptions.InterfaceError: (0, '')

and the file

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost",user="user", passwd="pass", db="example")
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    sys.exit (1)
try:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
    row = cursor.fetchone ()
    print "server version:", row[0]
    cursor.close ()
except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
    #sys.exit (1)
conn.close ()
```

[user@localhost]$ python b.py

> Error 0: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "b.py", line 18, in 
>      conn.close()
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: closing a closed connection

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your try block runs successfully then you are closing your connection twice. I think you can put it in finally block, that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indent the second conn.close(), otherwise you're closing a closed connection after a successful query.

Comment: If I indent the second conn.close() it still doesn't display the version, and it gives the same error

Comment: Sorry... looking at this with fresh eyes, now understanding that debugging b.py is not your objective, but understanding your connection problem is.

Comment: My guess is that the connection was closed internally for some reason. What happens if you do "print conn.open" just before your second "try" block?

Comment: Looking around a bit, this error seems to crop up when a duplicate connection is open in another module or process. Is there any chance you've got something else sitting on this connection?

Comment: print conn.open = 1, then I do the execute and it brings the same error and then conn.open = 0

Comment: @El_Feto Neat. I think it's safe to say that it's not a programming error on your part. Now the real fun begins, because you may have a compile/install/package problem. FWIW, it may be worth trying the pure-Python library mysql-connector-python while you're troubleshooting that build problem. They both implement DB-API, so it should be easy enough to switch back later if you need to.